# How to place images instead placeholders wordpress with bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, image, placeholder

I need to place the images instead gray placeholders images in my theme in Wordpress with the bootstrap template.How can I do in automatically?
Please, can you attach the link with information about this?

Comment: Can you provide link to your site where you're using this theme? or code sample, if working offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will help you but this solution used jQuery,

```
$('.member a').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();    
        if(text == 'Unlock'){
            $(this).html(text.replace('Unlock', "<img src='"+templateUrl+"/image/unblck.png'"+" />"));      
        }else{
            $(this).html(text.replace('lock', "<img src='"+templateUrl+"/image/blck.png'"+" />"));
        }
    });
```